# Array or object conditions

Tags: angularjs

I am learning Angular and have some hotel room prices. However if you are staying more than 1 night the data that is returned in NightlyRate is in an array otherwise it is in an object.

I'm not sure on how to approach this? Can I do this inline in the view or should I do this in the controller or model?

I need to add an `ng-repeat` if it is more than 1 night

**If 1 night**

```
{{roomPrices.NightlyRatesPerRoom.NightlyRate['@baseRate']}}

"NightlyRatesPerRoom": {
"@size": "1",
"NightlyRate": {
  "@baseRate": "154.55",
  "@rate": "154.55",
  "@promo": "false"
}
```

},

**If more than 1 night**

```
<div ng-repeat="roomPrice in roomPrices.NightlyRatesPerRoom.NightlyRate">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <p>Night {{$index+1}}:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <p class="text-xs-right">${{roomPrice['@baseRate']}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
 </div>

"NightlyRatesPerRoom": {
"@size": "3",
"NightlyRate": [
  {
    "@baseRate": "154.55",
    "@rate": "154.55",
    "@promo": "false"
  },
  {
    "@baseRate": "154.55",
    "@rate": "154.55",
    "@promo": "false"
  },
  {
    "@baseRate": "154.55",
    "@rate": "154.55",
    "@promo": "false"
  }
]
```

},

Comment: Why don't you just make it an array regardless of how many nights?

Comment: The data is coming from a 3rd party API, so I can't change it

Comment: Would it better to ng-if or ng-show from the controller?

Comment: @ottz0 yes, you can. Just do it in the success callback of the http request.

Answer (score -1):

You can see below... to identify if it is object or Array

```
   var objnight = roomPrices.NightlyRatesPerRoom.NightlyRate;


     if(Object.prototype.toString.call(objnight).toString() == "[object Array]"){
      alert("array")
    }else if( Object.prototype.toString.call(objnight).toString()=="[object Object]"){
   alert(object)
}
```

Comment: This terrible advice. Instead of this you can use `angular.isArray`.